# 18.04 hanging problem

Tags: boot, shutdown, restart

I have installed ubuntu 18.04 in my dell inspiron 3551 and having problem during shutdown/restart. The laptop gets hang and the shutdown does not completes successfully.

Also when I move down the flap of my laptop and move it back the system gets hanged on the same screen I left it.

In both cases I have to forcefully turn down my laptop by pressing the power key for few secs. Tried adding GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force" in the grub file but nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with my Lenovo Yoga initially but it seems to have gone away after I selected to use Nvidia proprietary driver. Well, at least the lock-up does not happen as often anymore. It may or may not tbe steps that fixed the problem as I also did a few upgrades along the way.

You can try that and if that doesn't work, try upgrading the kernel to the latest supported one using

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If that doesn't fix your problem either, try changing the greeter back to lightdm

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```